# не отрабатывает скрипт

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

не подскажите почему только по первому img отрабатывает скрипт, если нажимаю на другие кроме 1 не работает, если на первый то все загружает во фрейм и работает

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


 $(function() {
  $('#popup, #hide-layout').hide(); // скрыли фон и всплывающее окно
  $('#hide-layout').css({opacity: .5}); // кроссбраузерная прозрачность
  alignCenter($('#popup')); // центрировали окно
  $(window).resize(function() {
    alignCenter($('#popup')); // центрирование при ресайзе окна
  })
  $('#click-me').click(function() {
    $('#hide-layout, #popup').fadeIn(300); // плавно открываем
  var title = $('#vmi').attr("title");
 alert(title);
 document.getElementById('videoFrame').src =title;

  })
  $('.closeic, #hide-layout').click(function() {
    $('#hide-layout, #popup, .popup').fadeOut(300); // плавно скрываем
   $('#hide-layout, #popup, .popup, #glisse-overlay').hide();
   document.getElementById('videoFrame').src = "not.found/404"

  })
  $('#sendLetter').click(function() {
    alert('Выполнили какое-то действие, затем скрываем окно...'); // сделали что-то...
    $('#hide-layout, #popup').fadeOut(300); // скрыли
  $('#hide-layout, #popup, .popup, #glisse-wrapper').hide();

  })
  // функция центрирования
  function alignCenter(elem) {
    elem.css({
      left: ($(window).width() - elem.width()) / 2 + 'px', // получаем координату центра по ширине
      top: ($(window).height() - elem.height()) / 2 + 'px' // получаем координату центра по высоте
    })
  }
})
    });
```

```html
       <ul class="stack" data-count="1">
                <li><a href="#" id="click-me"><img id="vmi" src="/images/video/2_v.jpg" class="tl" title="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=km2D8Q2fRnk?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" /></a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="stack stack1" data-count="1">
                <li><a href="#" id="click-me"><img id="vmi" src="/images/video/3_v.jpg" class="tl" title="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fk3sun0SSRU?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" /></a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="stack" data-count="1">
                <li><a href="#" id="click-me"><img id="vmi" src="/images/video/4_v.jpg" class="tl" title="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A7taZflbegE?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" /></a></li>
            </ul> 
            <ul class="stack" data-count="1">
                <li><a href="#" id="click-me"><img id="vmi" src="/images/video/5_v.jpg" class="tl" title="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gJc8XqA-1og?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" /></a></li>
            </ul>


<div id="popup" class="popup">
     <div class="Bg-popup">
           <div class="form-popup">
           <a href="#" class="closeic">
              <img src="/wp-content/themes/cbsmedia/images/cross-out.png" width="20" height="20">
           </a>
           <div class="videopop">
           <iframe id="videoFrame" width="853" height="480" src="" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
           </div>

           </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Где у вас функция "входа", какая именно из функций click не отрабатывает?  Может вы не верное сочетание классов задали img? Приведите *минимальный* фрагмент кода и укажите строчку/функцию где возникает ошибка.

Comment: Потому что нельзя задавать одинаковый id нескольким элементам на странице, поменяйте на класс и всё будет хорошо

Comment: class  не работает

Comment: $('#click-me').click(function() {
    $('#hide-layout, #popup').fadeIn(300); // плавно открываем
  var title = $('#vmi').attr("title");
 alert(title);
 document.getElementById('videoFrame').src =title;

  })
не отрабатыает, не открывает видео кроме первого и не берет значение с title

Comment: Потому что нельзя задавать одинаковый id нескольким элементам на странице, поменяйте на класс и всё будет хорошо – MasterAlex 2 часа назад
пробовал вместо id="vmi" class="vmi" и все ровно не работает